iText7 PDF XObject is not properly fitted into PdfCanvas frame
I am adding a PDF annotation with appearance stream via iText7 below, where it suppose to draw an ink within the canvas on top left rectangle, but it was shown and located at lower left bottom, apparently it is doesn't fit correctly into the canvas rectangle frame.
How am I suppose to change it's behavior to always start within the frame rather than lower-left bottom? Or did I do it in the wrong matter? Previously the same logic works on older version of iText - iTextSharp.
    private PdfAnnotation CreateAnnotation(PdfPage page)
    {
    var rect = new Rectangle((float)1.63, (float)762.69, (float)28.25, (float)33.5);

    var pdfAnnotation = PdfAnnotation.MakeAnnotation(new PdfDictionary());

    pdfAnnotation.SetRectangle(new PdfArray(rect));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.Contents, new PdfString("Text"));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.Title, new PdfString("Title"));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Annot);
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.Subtype, new PdfName("Ink"));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(new PdfName("Subj"), new PdfString("Pencil"));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.CreationDate, new PdfDate(DateTime.Now).GetPdfObject());
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.M, new PdfDate(DateTime.Now).GetPdfObject());
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber(PdfAnnotation.PRINT));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.CA, new PdfNumber(100));
    var dict = new PdfDictionary();
    dict.Put(PdfName.S, new PdfName(""));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.BS, dict);
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("Rich text"));

    var inkListArray = new PdfArray(new double[] { 20.25, 29.13, 20.38, 29.13, 21.13, 29.01, 23.63, 27.88, 30.13, 24.88, 35.38, 22.26, 40.25, 19.51, 44, 17.13, 46.38, 15.26, 47.75, 14.63, 48, 13.63, 48, 13.38 });
    pdfAnnotation.SetColor(new DeviceRgb(255, 0, 0));
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.InkList, inkListArray);
    pdfAnnotation.Put(PdfName.BorderThickness, new PdfNumber(5));

    var xObj = new PdfFormXObject(rect);
    var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    canvas.Rectangle(rect);

    var pdfAnnotationAppearance = new PdfAnnotationAppearance();
    pdfAnnotationAppearance.SetState(PdfName.Normal, xObj);

    canvas.AddXObjectFittedIntoRectangle(xObj, rect);

    // set line width, stroke and fill colours
    var black = DeviceRgb.BLACK;
    canvas.SetLineWidth(2);
    canvas.SetStrokeColor(black);

    var border = 1;
    foreach (var match in PathRegex.Matches("M0,0L0.13,0C0.25,0,0.50,0,0.88,0.12C1.25,0.25,1.75,0.50,3.38,1.25C5,2.00,7.75,3.25,9.88,4.25C12,5.25,13.50,6,15.13,6.87C16.75,7.75,18.50,8.75,20,9.62C21.50,10.50,22.75,11.25,23.75,12.00C24.75,12.75,25.50,13.50,26.13,13.87C26.75,14.25,27.25,14.25,27.50,14.50C27.75,14.75,27.75,15.25,27.75,15.50L27.75,15.75").OfType<Match>        ().Where(x => x.Success))
    {
   switch (match.Groups["type"].Value)
   {
       case "M":
           if (ParseNumbers(match.Groups["values"], 2, out var moveValues))
           {
               canvas.MoveTo(moveValues[0] + border, height - moveValues[1] + border);
           }
           break;
       case "L":
           if (ParseNumbers(match.Groups["values"], 2, out var lineValues))
           {
               canvas.LineTo(lineValues[0] + border, height - lineValues[1] + border);
           }
           break;
       case "C":
           if (ParseNumbers(match.Groups["values"], 6, out var curveValues))
           {
               canvas.CurveTo(
                   curveValues[0] + border,
                   height - curveValues[1] + border,
                   curveValues[2] + border,
                   height - curveValues[3] + border,
                   curveValues[4] + border,
                   height - curveValues[5] + border
               );
           }
           break;
        }
    }

    // stroke path
    canvas.Stroke();

    // release canvas
    canvas.Release();

    // set the normal appearance
    pdfAnnotation.SetNormalAppearance(pdfAnnotationAppearance);

    return pdfAnnotation;
}

void AddPdfNumbers(PdfArray parent, params float[] numbers)
{
    if (parent == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        parent.Add(new PdfNumber(number));
    }
}


Sample PDFs generated by iText7 and iTextSharp
https://filebin.net/wx840u4t5wjqw2wc/itext_example.pdf
https://filebin.net/wx840u4t5wjqw2wc/itextSharp_example.pdf

I find the difference between iTextSharp is it seems to render the drawing directly within the frame after setting it's appearance stream, but after migrating to iText7, doing the same way seems to follow page coordination instead, which starts from bottom left.
I would like to know by using iText7, do I need to specially force the starting points to be from the frame instead.
